# Breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: angular, debugging, vscode-debugger

I wanted to use vscode extension ( Debugger for Chrome ), but whatever I try I can't get rid of the 'breakpoint set but not yet bound'.

Everything is running, the debugger console is showing all the console log messages but I can hit the debug point.

Here is my launch.json

```
{
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
```

I am using Angular and its running inside Docker. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Your **`launch.json`** should be as follows

```
{
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Chrome",
   "url": "http://localhost:4200",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
   "sourceMaps": true,
   "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
       "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
       "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
       "/*": "*",
       "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this working snippet! Would love some explanation if possible. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your webRoot setting is pointing to the right directory of your angular project. It's likely that your `${workspaceFolder}` is referring to the top-level directory.

for example: Your source code is in `C:\projects\awesome_tool\client` but, your `${workspaceFolder}` is pointing to `C:\projects`. To fix this, you need to modify `webRoot`'s value in launch.json file as
`webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/awesome_tool/client`

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to a bug in @angular-devkit/build-angular. The fix was introduced [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/0224d2b92eda628a7edd0797d194e509953f67bb). Try installing the latest version

[Reference](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1262#issuecomment-517901418)